# Connecting ng-click to controller function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I am having trouble getting a partial's div's `ng-click` attribute to fire the function I want, called `testDivClicked()`.

In my application controller, I provide a route to a partial called `test`:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'myApp.main', 'myApp.test'])
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];

    function config($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {templateUrl: '/partials/main.html', controller: 'MainController', controllerAs: 'vm'})
            .when('/test', {templateUrl: '/partials/test/test.html', controller: 'TestController', controllerAs: 'vm'})
            .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
    }
})();
```

Here is the `test.html` partial that gets inserted into the parent view:

```
<div class="outer-holder test-outer-holder">
    <div class="middle-holder test-middle-holder">
        <div class="inner-holder test-inner-holder">
            <div class="test-container" ng-click="vm.testDivClicked('test-container')">
                <legend>Test</legend>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My `test` controller:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("myApp.test")
        .controller("TestController", TestController);

    TestController.$inject = [];

    function TestController() {
        var vm = this;

        function testDivClicked(msg) {
            console.log("message:", msg);
        }
    }
})();
```

When I click on the innermost `div`, I would like `testDivClicked()` to log that I clicked on it.

What am I missing in this setup, that would allow me to get `ng-click` to work?

Comment: try this `vm.testDivClicked = function(msg){ console.log("message:" , msg ): }`

Comment: Can you please provide a plunker.

Comment: Why don't you use angular $scope service? May i know your angularjs version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write `vm.testDivClicked = function(msg)` not `function testDivClicked`. You declared a local function.

Answer (score 0):

The module name `myApp.test` provided for creating controller is wrong. Instead use `angular.module("myApp")`

So your test controller should be

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("myApp")
        .controller("TestController", TestController);

    TestController.$inject = [];

    function TestController() {
        var vm = this;

        function testDivClicked(msg) {
            console.log("message:", msg);
        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

As said earlier by Alexander, the function `testDivClicked` function is not associated with `vm(this)`. so it is not recognized in the dom as  `vm.testDivClicked('test-container')`.

Here is the modified portion.

```
function TestController() {
        var vm = this;

      vm.testDivClicked = function(msg) {
            console.log("message:", msg);
        }
    }
```